# present or future in that case

Tags: present-tense

I will tell you when he comes and I don't know when he will come

when he comes answers to the question I will tell you **what?**  and when he will come answers to the same question I don't know **what**? when he will come. I will tell you and I don't know grammatically are the same (Am I right?)

So none of these questions answer to the question  When, so why one is **present** and the other **future**

Comment: in THIS case, not that case. The case you are talking about.  Answers the question, not answers to the question.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to ask, but this question is fairly similar to [your previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131338/the-difference-between-the-meanings-of-two-sentences).

Answer (score 0):

> I **will tell** you when he comes.
>   I don't know when he **will come**.

are both placed in the future, one speaks to when *you* will do an action, the other when *he* will do an action.